# Pass foreign key from one of two tables based on object type using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have two object types, `Movie` and `Episode`. Both of which implement the interface `ITitle` and are connected to one or more `MediaFile` objects.

The 3 relevant tables are `Movies`, `Episodes`, and `MediaFiles`.

I am trying to pass a foreign key of either `MovieId` (from the `Movies` table) or `EpisodeId` (from the `Episodes` table) to the `MediaFile` object, depending on what type of media it is.

Both the `Movie`/`Episode` and `MediaFile` must be able to be created with a single database write. So I cannot add the `Movie`/`Episode` then query the database to check what kind of media it is. It must also be possible to add a `MediaFile` to an existing `ITitle`. Each implementation of `ITitle` can have many `MediaFile` objects associated with it. `MediaFile` objects are dependent on `ITitle` objects and cannot be created without them.

At first I tried passing a `virtual ITitle` in `MediaFile` to get the foreign key like below:

```
public class Episode : ITitle {
    [Key]
    public int EpisodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TmdbId { get; set; }
    public int EpisodeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PosterUrl { get; set; }

    public bool Played { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }
    public TitleType TitleType { get; set; }

    // Foreign key from Seasons table
    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Season")]
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }
}

public class Movie : ITitle {
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TmdbId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PosterUrl { get; set; }

    public bool Played { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }
    public TitleType TitleType { get; set; }
}

public enum TitleType {
    Other,
    Episode,
    Movie,
    Featurette,
}

public interface ITitle {
    public bool Played { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }
    public TitleType TitleType { get; set; }
}


public class MediaFile{
    [Key]
    public int MediaFileId { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public TitleType TitleType { get; set; }

    // Foreign key from either Movies table or Episodes table
    // this does not work, throws error
    public virtual ITitle MovieOrEpisode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TODO TableName")]
    public ITitle EpisodeOrMovieId { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to get the foreign key by passing a `virtual ITitle MovieOrEpisode` causes this error when adding a database migration (and there's no single table to check for this key in):

`The property 'MediaFile.MovieOrEpisode' is of an interface type ('ITitle'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

I then tried making an abstract class `Title` that `Movie` and `Episode` inherit, but this grouped both into the same table, which is not what I want.

I also tried using 2 fields, `MovieId` and `EpisodeId`, instead of the single `EpisodeOrMovieId`. This gave me the desired result, but I feel like this is not good practice, seeing as one column should always be `NULL`.

```
public class MediaFile{
    [Key]
    public int MediaFileId { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public TitleType TitleType { get; set; }

    // Foreign key from either Movies table or Episodes table
    // this uses 2 fields where one is null and the other is used
    public virtual Episode Episode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Episode")]
    public int? EpisodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Movie")]
    public int? MovieId { get; set; }
}
```

My only other idea is to add some kind of intermediate table with the fields `EpisodeOrMovieId` and `TitleType`, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

I am using .NET Core 3.1, Entity Framework Core 3.1 (code-first), and SQLite provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity framework, the `DbSet<...>` represent the tables in your database, the type in the DbSet represents the type of the rows in the table.

> The non-virtual properties represent the columns in the table, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

As your database classes represent your tables, these classes, should be POCO's: only get/set properties, no fancy things like methods and interfaces.

All extra functionality should be in extension methods, or even better in a wrapper class that hides the structure of your database tables.

The latter method is quite often called a repository pattern: all you know is that the repository is able to store some data permanently. You can store data, retrieve it back update and delete data. How it is stored (database? CSV-file? XML? Json?) is hidden, also the structure of the tables. The repository is  an adapter of the database to your actual usage of the database.

This has the advantage that you can change the internal structure of your tables without having to change the users of your repository. You can provide structures that internally would need (group-)joining tables, without users knowing it, and it makes testing of the software that uses your repository easier: you don't need a real database to implement your repository.

Your awkward feeling about the two foreign keys is normal. However, it is quite common in databases if you say that an item relates to either elements from table A or table B, that you have two foreign keys.

One solution would be, to extract the values of the `ITitle` from the `Movies` and the `Episodes` and put them in a separate `Titles` table. `Movies` will have a foreign key to its `Title`, `Episodes` will have a foreign key to its `Title`.

Whether this is a good solution depends on what database actions you will be doing most. It can be expected that the fields in a database are much less changed than queries. The reason is that usually a change is made after the operator has typed the changed data. So we'll focus on queries.

What will you query more:

- Give me the MediaFiles with their Movies and Episodes with their Titles that ...
- Give me all Movie MediaFiles with their Titles that ..., don't bother about Episodes
- Give me all MediaFiles, with their Movies / Episodes, without their Titles that ... (unlikely)

Similar queries can be asked about Movies or Episodes: do you want the Title or not?

If you always want Titles in your queries, and you would have a separate Titles table, then every query that involves a Movie or an Episode would need an extra join with the Titles table.

The solution with two foreign keys seems to be way more efficient: As soon as you've got a Movie from the database, you already have the Title. When asking for Movie MediaFiles is a Join with two tables, instead of three. Similar for Episode media files. If you want MediaFiles of Movies and Episodes that ..., it is always a join with three tables, not four.

It can be that your entrance to the data is Title based:

- Give me all Titles that start with ... or contains words ...
- Given some Titles, give me all Movies and Episodes with that Title

If this kind of queries needs to be fast: operator queries titles, and after a title is selected the search for movies or episode with that title starts, then a separate Title table would be faster.

In modern times, storage is not an issue anymore, processing power is the limit. So when deciding whether to have your Title properties within a separate table, or as properties within Movies and within Episodes, you should first ask yourself: what kind of queries do I ask most? What kind of queries will result in large results? What kind of queries will the operator be impatiently waiting for?

I guess the starting point is Titles, so try to optimize these.